# concatenating local variable to parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am sending 2 parameters to SQL stored procedure. It works, but it doesn't when I try to concatenate a local variable with it.

This works:

```
exec DeansSMSDB.dbo.ADD_SMS_InQueue @CellNo, 'Dear customer, Your complaint has been registered and your complaint no. is'
```

but this doesn't:

```
exec DeansSMSDB.dbo.ADD_SMS_InQueue @CellNo, 'Dear customer, Your complaint has been registered and your complaint no. is' + @ComplaintID
```

I need to concatenate @ComplaintID, but how?

Comment: If you look at the syntax for [`EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188332.aspx) you'll see that you can supply a *value* or a *variable*. What's not there (and would be if what you're attempting was allowed) is an *expression*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another variable:

```
declare @arg varchar(8000) = 'Dear customer, Your complaint has been registered and your complaint no. is' + cast(@ComplaintID as varchar(255);

exec DeansSMSDB.dbo.ADD_SMS_InQueue @CellNo, @arg;
```

Note that if `@ComplaintId` is numeric, you need to cast it to a string to use the `+` operator as a string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

**You could try a two step approach in which you dump the results of the execution into a small @T temp table. And then do a quick select from that @T with concatenation**:

1. create table tableX (input_field_name varchar(20) NULL,
                        output_field_name varchar(20) NULL)
2. insert tableX values ('address','addr')
3. create procedure testP as 
   select input_field_name from tableX where output_field_name = 'addr'
4. declare @T table (F1 varchar(20))
   declare @v varchar(10) = 'my'
5. insert @T
   exec testP
6. select @v + ' ' + F1 from @T